# MVC and N-Tier Architecture

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, n-tier-architecture

I started off wondering where in an MVC pattern the business Layer should be.
That quickly led me to asking "what is the difference between n-tier and MVC".
I read a lot of articles and Stackoverflow responses and found that there were as money different opinions as there were replies.

I'm not an expert but I thought that some of the replies and articles were just rubbish.  e.g.
N-tier is when each tier is on physically different hardware in the network (nah!)
N-tier is for large applications and MVC is for small (Rubbish)

Then I read one which made sense.  N-tier process always flows UI to BL to DL and back again through BL to the UI. However, MVC has that Triangular process flow.  True, but is that all ?

Another point someone made was that MVC was an application architecture model and n-tier was a System Architecture mode.  I wasn't sure what they meant by that till they mentioned that  the MVC pattern being an application architecture could be used in each of the n-tier layers.

Having just been reading about Angular I could see MVC being implemented in the UI layer and seeing how MVC and Web API have just recently merged in .Net I could see a Web AP middle layer with controllers, views and models.

But would that hold up for the DL ?  Most data layers in .Net these days are the EntityFrame work with some wrapping.  Could the DL tier be implemented with an MVC pattern or in fact should it be ?

If this definition of N-tier and MVC is correct then it should be possible to apply the MVC model to any layer in an N-tier system layer.

Can anyone give me any indication if that is feasible or if you should even be bothered with the DAL being MVC.

Answer (score 0):

In a way, yes.  It's possible to implement something akin to MVC in the data layer.  In particular, views, models, and control (not necessarily a controllerER though).

Take, for example, SQL Server.  You can create a message passing architecture that allows you to create an API to access data so that even if the underlying model (tables) changes, the API does not.

Remember, however, that the "data layer" tends to refer to code though, rather than the physical tier.  You data access layer is typically an API, model, or repository that encapsulates the data and morphs it into an application layer compatible set of data.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, application/business layer should be in the controller component, whilst object should be in the model component and UI in the view component.
In an MVC web app, a controller should also handle http GET and POST requests and return views.
You can also combine MVC with N-Tier… putting business logic in a different class/classes, taking it out of the controller, especially if you need to apply/use a method in different parts of your application, that way you can call it from any controller of an app, reducing duplicate code and having maintainable code.

Remember, you can have multiple controllers directing/handling their own views & models in MVC, so what’s the point of leaving the business/application logic in it, when some logic may be applied on other controllers (you end up copying/duplicating code).

Both architectures/design patters have their own advantages and limitations, and personally by using both, you can achieve more flexibility and scalability.

Have a look at my application architecture diagram using a hyrbid model of both design patterns here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/d1e6ha/a_diagram_of_an_mvc_ntier_hybrid_model_which_i/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf